# ComboBox WindowForms

Tags: .net, winforms

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDetails1;Integrated Security=True";
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into EmployeeDetails(Name,Gender,JobPosition,JobStatus)values(@name,@gender,@jobposition,@jobstatus)";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        SqlParameter pa1 = new SqlParameter("@name", DbType.String);
        pa1.Value = txtName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pa1);


        SqlParameter pa2 = new SqlParameter("@gender", DbType.String);

        if (rdiobtnFemale.Checked)
        {
            pa2.Value = rdiobtnFemale.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            pa2.Value = rdiobtnMale.Text;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pa2);


        SqlParameter pa3 = new SqlParameter("@JobPosition", DbType.String);

        if (chkboxManager.Checked)
        {
            pa3.Value = chkboxManager.Text;
        }
        if (chkboxExecutive.Checked)
        {
            pa3.Value = pa3.Value + " " + chkboxExecutive.Text;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pa3);


        SqlParameter pa4 = new SqlParameter("@JobStatus", DbType.String);
        pa4.Value = cmbboxJobStatus.SelectedItem.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pa4);

        da.InsertCommand = cmd;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Name To Get Results");
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDetails1;Integrated Security=True";
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from EmployeeDetails where Name=@name";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        SqlParameter pa1 = new SqlParameter("@name", DbType.String);
        pa1.Value = txtName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pa1);

        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);

        chkboxManager.Checked = false;
        chkboxExecutive.Checked = false;
        rdiobtnFemale.Checked = false;
        rdiobtnMale.Checked = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string str, str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6;
            str = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            str1 = chkboxManager.Text;
            str2 = chkboxExecutive.Text;
            str3 = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
            str4 = rdiobtnFemale.Text;
            str5 = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();


            //checkbox
            if (str == str1)
            {

                chkboxManager.Checked = true;
            }
            if (str == str2)
            {
                chkboxExecutive.Checked = true;
            }
            if (str == str1 + " " + str2)
            {
                chkboxExecutive.Checked = true;
                chkboxManager.Checked = true;
            }

            //radio button
            if (str3 == str4)
            {
                rdiobtnFemale.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                rdiobtnMale.Checked = true;
            }

            //combobox

            str6 = cmbboxJobStatus.Items[i].ToString();
            if (str5 == str6)
            {

                cmbboxJobStatus.Text = str6;
            }


        }


    }
}
```

}

> There are values such as "Permanent", "OnContract" etc mentioned in the             ComboBox. I have got these values inserted into the database on a insert button click. On click of the show button i want the  program to search the database table and fetch me the record whose name i have mentioned in the textbox. the details of combo box should also be displayed as and what is mentioned in the database.

Comment: Is this a windows form application or asp.net?

Comment: @attila Windows Form.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @Tewr I v edited the code as well as the question. plz look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a missile to kill mosquito :-]

Anyway you just need to check if your combobox contains the item retrieved from database, and then set it using SelectedText property. You need to replace the code below

```
str6 = cmbboxJobStatus.Items[i].ToString();
if (str5 == str6)
{

    cmbboxJobStatus.Text = str6;
}
```

With this one

```
if (cmbboxJobStatus.Items.Contains(str5))
{
    cmbboxJobStatus.SelectedText = str5;
}
```

Comment: This code that you have suggested doesn't work in the context of my code.